# Correlated subquery - Group by in inner query and rewrite to window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking at this query:

```
select ID, date1 
from  table1 as t1
where date2 = (select max(date2) 
                from table1 as t2
                where t1.ID = t2.ID
                group by t2.ID)
```

First of all I don't think the `Group by` is necessary. Am I right? Second is it generally more efficint to rewrite this as a window function?

Does this look right?

```
select ID, date1
from (select ID, date1, row_number() over(partition by ID) as row_num,
                  max(date2) over(partition by ID) as max_date 
      from  table1)
where row_num = 1;
```

Comment: you missed the alias for your second query `from table1) as t1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all I don't think the Group by is necessary. Am I right?

You are correct. That's a scalar subquery anyway: `group by` doesn't change the result since we are filtering on a single `ID`. Not using `group by` makes the intent clearer in my opinion.

The window function solution does not need `max()` - the filtering is sufficient, but the window function needs an `order by` clause (and the derived table needs an alias). So:

```
select ID, date1
from (
    select ID, date1, row_number() over(partition by ID order by date1 desc) as row_num
    from table1
) t1
where row_num = 1;
```

That's not *exactly* the same thing as the first query, because it does not allow ties, while the first query does. Use `rank()` if you want the exact same logic.

Which query performs better highly depends on your data and structure. The correlated subquery would take advantage of an index on `(id, date2)`. Both solutions are canonical approaches to the problem, and you would probably need to test both solutions against your data to see which one is better in your context.

Comment: Thanks! There is a columnstore index on the table. I don't want to change anything on the table. I don't know so much about columnstore yet... Can you advice based on this info?

Comment: So for  `rank()` one could filter two rows in each partition. I think this solution with `row_number` is more correct because the output is being joined and with the `rank` or the original subquiery there can be duplicates.. Right? PS website says I have to wait to accept the answer..

Comment: @darw when max is not unique in the `rank` i.e. when we filter by `row_num` and use `rank` we keep two rows..